# IIS 10 Three sites using Headers, 1 works 2 time-out

Tags: wordpress, azure, iis, dns, timeout

I have an issue with an IIS10 webserver.

It was initially created to host one of our websites which works using HTTPS.

I then created two new sites and migrated from LAMP to IIS10. The sites work perfectly locally using hosts URL redirect but when I updated the DNS for the 2nd two sites they both return "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

All three sites are Wordpress. One site (the working site) is SSL, the other two aren't.

All Three sites where migrated from Unix Webservers.

The IIS10 Webserver is a virtual machine in our Azure Infrastructure

All Three are setup identical apart from the SSL Certificate on the first site.

Can anyone help with suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things that you might need to check:

- Do you have a unique IP/port for each website?
- If using a custom port, are you appending that to the DNS name in the request?
- Do you have any local host file entries that are leading your DNS queries astray?
- Do you have any local firewall rules on the webserver, or endpoint ACLs/Network Security groups in Azure that are restricting your traffic (might be an issue if you're using a non-standard port)

If you're still having problems, can you advise on:

1. from where are you attempting to resolve the website? (i.e. same
   machine, same network, or from your work network)
2. each sites configured IP & port combination (you should obfuscate the
   last two octets of the IPs when posting)

Regards,
Stephen Malone - Azure Networking